# Windows shared printer not shown

Tags: printer

I have installed Elementary OS loki on my T400 notebook.(old but works flawlessly lol )

I have a NAS server which has virtualbox installed. There is a virtual machine with windows installed and my printer is shared via this virtual machine. This is done because my printer is so ancient it doesn't work with the print plugin on the NAS box.

I can see my printer via a laptop running windows 7 and it prints fine. I can also see it from my desktop PC running linux mint 17.3 and again it prints with no issue. On my T400 I had Linux mint 18.1 and again that found the printer and it worked perfectly. Only now I have elementary on this laptop it is not found. Elementary does list the printer but that id directly from the NAS not the virtual machine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed!

You need to install SMBclient (I did it through synaptic package manager) once done you then have the option to look for a SMB shared printer in the printers app.

Comment: Please add the command for installing smbclient for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: As written I installed Synaptic package manger not via the terminal. I thought this easier than rather than going through the terminal. Synaptic package manager is available via the app store on Elementary.                                                      if you need to install via the terminal it should be                                      sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smbclient

Comment: That's not the point of my comment. At least include (in your answer) the name of the package as it is in the repository (for the benefit of others). Remember everyone is at a different level.

Comment: Apologies. I understood that you wanted the command. The package is smbclient which is what was in my original post. If you need more info ill try and help im a pretty new user myself so maybe not getting what you really want.

Comment: Lol no worries. I've been using Linux for 10 years now, so I'm not confused or anything. It's actually for the benefit of others that I'd asked you to include that info.